# How to count the number of repetitions for every single number?

Tags: lua, coronasdk

So I have a `for loop` that loops 100 times and each time it generates a random number from 1 to 100. For some statistics, I need to count how many times **each number** repeats. I have no idea how to make it other than manually.

```
One = 0
Two = 0
Three = 0
Four = 0
Five = 0
for i=1, 100 do
  number = GetRandomNumber(1, 5, 1.5)
  if number == 1 then
    One = One + 1
  elseif number == 2 then
    Two = Two + 1
  elseif number == 3 then
    Three = Three + 1
  elseif number == 4 then
    Four = Four + 1
  elseif number == 5 then
    Five = Five + 1
  end
end
```

This is how I currently count, but I don't want to manually type for every number. How can I make this simpler?

Answer (score 4):

I do it as such:

```
number_counter, number = {}, 0
for i = 1, 100 do
  number = GetRandomNumber(1, 5, 1.5)
  if number_counter[number] then
    number_counter[number] = number_counter[number] + 1
  else
    number_counter[number] = 1
  end
end
```

This is, of course, assuming there are no half points (not sure what the 1.5 is for). Then you can just call `number_counter[#]` to see what its value is.